# How to avoid iframe embedding code?

Tags: css, iframe

I want to change the style of my text that I am embedding with the following markup

```
<iframe src="URL">
```

My web page has a limited amount of characters that can be used up very fast with coding in CSS and HTML. The code I'm using the iframe to embed is this:

```
<style type="text/css">

body {
    color: black;
}

h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

h2 {
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
}

</style>

<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

But when I'm using the following to embed it:

```
<iframe src="THE RAW URL of the code above" frameBorder="0">
```

...the whole code is showing, not just the `Hello World!` in #FFFFFF.

What am I doing wrong here? I would embed just the `Hello World!` but I know that the CSS on the parent page will not change the style of the source I'm putting in the iframe.

Comment: After using <iframe src="URL" frameBorder="0"> The whole code shows rather than just "Hello World!" how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the iframe is for embedding HTML documents, you should try using a fully valid HTML as your external file. Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>iframe example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
        color: black;
    }

    h1 {
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    h2 {
        color: rgb(255,255,255);
    }
  </style>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah, forgive me. I'm using Pastebin for the style code and text. I'm using the Raw Pastebin link of the code. What did you mean by this? Do I put all of that into my webpage? Or do I put that into my Pastebin and iframe src it on the webpage?

Comment: I see, the problem is that what you are getting from Pastebin is not an HTML file, but a Text file. When your website calls the file from Pastebin into the iFrame, and tries to parse the content, it won't parse it as HTML, but as a regular text file. That is why it is showing all your code.

Comment: Basically, do not use Pastebin for this. You need something that will produce valid HTML. It can be [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), [Codepen](http://codepen.io/), or anything similar.

Comment: This will be much better for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689676/stylesheet-not-displaying-within-div-id-tab I've included my webpage's code here. I figured that this question didn't make much sense, but this question covers everything, I think. I've decided to use stylesheet over iframe now that I know iframe is basically a hole in a webpage that displays another, but yet i'm having nothing display with stylesheet now. This is such a hassle...