# Stylesheet not displaying within div id tab?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

This is the code on my webpage, I'm trying to make my stylesheet that says "Hello!" display on TAB1, but it isn't displaying. What changes need to be made to display my stylesheet from Pastebin in TAB1? I was able to do this in the past but now I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong here.

MY WEBPAGE IS VERY LIMITED with characters, so I MUST use Pastebin to put all of my writing into my page, since I only have another 2000-2200 characters left that I can use, which is definitely only enough for coding, not putting walls of text on each tab I'll be making, as well.

```
<style>

    body{
    color:#000000;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:Ebrima;
    background-image: url() !important;
    background-color:#FFFFFF !important;
    background-position:bottom-center !important;
    background-repeat:repeat !important;}

    h1{
    margin:0px 0px 0px;
    font-size: 10px;
    color:#FF0000;
    font-family:Ebrima;
    letter-spacing:0px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #880000;}

    b, strong { font-family: Ebrima; font-size: 12px;line-height: 10px; font-weight: bold;
    color: #FF5555;}

    i, em {color:#FF0000; font-family: Ebrima; font-size:12px;}

    #navi{
    display: inline;
    padding:40px;
    color:#444444;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 12px 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family:Garamond;
    background: #;
    transition: all .2s;
    -o-transition: all .2s;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s;
    -moz-transition: all .2s;}

    #navi:hover{
    color:#FF0000;
    cursor:hand;
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity: .80;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Garamond;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80);
    transition: all .2s;
    -o-transition: all .2s;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s;
    -moz-transition: all .2s;}

    #A{
    left:0px;
    width: 100%;
    top:15px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    height: 0px;
    background:url('http://i.imgur.com/TebRLUr.png');}

    #B{margin-top:150px;}

    #C{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:20px;
    width:99%;
    height:70%;
    background-color:#;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding:0px;
    overflow:auto;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 6px; height: 4px; background: #; }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { background-color: #222222; border: 1px solid #000000;-webkit-border-radius: 1ex; }


    #navi a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#666;}

    #navi a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#666;}

    </style>



    <div id="A">
    <div id="B">
    <span id="navi" onclick="document.getElementById('start').innerHTML=document.getElementById('a').innerHTML;">TAB1</span>
    </div>
    </div>





    <div id="C">
    <div id="start">

<font color="#FF0000">This is the opening page!</font>

    </div>

    <div id="a" style="display:none;">

<font color="#FF0000">This is TAB1!</font>

<br>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=faJtrCxF">

<br>

<font color="#FF0000">The stylesheet will not display inside of this tab. Why?</font>


    </div>
</style>
```

Comment: when are web pages limited by charecters?

Comment: css declaration should always be inside head tag and not in the body of the document. Also font is not more a valid tag. Then, if this is the whole html of your page you are missing many parts of a valid html structure. Last but not least you are trying to embed a php page in a css tag. Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I used the wrong term. This code is for a profile on a social media website, I call it my webpage since I control the way my profile is displayed. I'm limited in characters when I'm coding the way my profile looks and I'm practicing at the moment. Anyway, what I'm trying to achieve is displaying the text "Hello!" that's in the Pastebin link I'm using the stylesheet for to put it into <div id="a" style="display:none;"> What changes do I need to make to display "Hello" in <div id="a"> ? the Pastebin link is in the code. Here it is: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=faJtrCxF

Comment: @JordanEvans well 1, you can't have <h1> hello </h1> show up if its being read as css, you have an extra style tag on the bottom of the page

Comment: basically, what you're trying to accomplished, can't be accomplished....

Comment: I could use <iframe src="URL"> and just use text, but then it'll only appear as default color and font. Whereas I'm planning to use a black background for the profile, which would make the text invisible, basically... There's nothing I can do?

Comment: you can move the tag out of the stylesheet and leave it on the page itself? i don't think you can just do what you're trying to do, if the social media account has a limit on the amount of charecters i'm suprised they even allow you to load external links to begin with

Comment: Oh, actually the stylesheet isn't working at all... I just tried using it without the tag and it's not displaying "Hello!" by itself. Is it possible that the administrator of the website made it so nobody can use stylesheet to obtain more characters than what they limit a user to now? Because I used to do this and it worked.

Comment: there's a new answer underneath but he's right, pastebin is not designed for this, at all. but i'm going to go on a limb and say yes. Its usually a security thing and i don't know why they would have you write all your html, css and js in one very limited code area... there's no logic to how that works, since pages by default don't have a maximum length (css has some maximum lengths for old browers but its by and large not an issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the same as in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688323/how-to-avoid-iframe-embedding-code) Pastebin will not generate a valid CSS file, but a text file.

Think of it in this way. Your website interprets your styles from a file with an extension of .css
If this file is not .css but something else, it won't work.

Pastebin will not export your code as .css even if what is inside it is valid CSS code. The reason for this is that the service they provide is not hosting, but a way of sharing code snippets, that is why they only export what you create there as text files.

What you want to do is not possible with Pastebin.

Is there a special reason for having the css hosted somewhere else? it is generally not a good idea, unless you want to use a CDN service.

PD: Don't use the `<font>` tag, this has been deprecated. Use instead a combination of `<p>`, `<span>`, `<h#>` and add classes to them when you need specific styles.

Comment: Alright, thank you for clearing this matter up. I think I'll use codepen from now on.

Comment: @Daemedeor Oh, no I wasn't on about using codepen for this, I was referring to what 1cgonza mentioned on my other question. But yeah, I know what I'm trying to do can't be achieved now. I'll have to start over, thanks for trying to help guys. I know a fix for this anyway, I'll just create a transparent PNG image in Photoshop and write my text in the image and then save it to an image hosting website and <img src="URL"> it into <div id="a"> It won't be text, but it'll be something to read at least. Haha.

Answer (score 0):

```
#navi:after{
   content:"Hello";
}
```

Will work, as you mentioned.

Comment: I've edited my question. It wasn't clear enough why it was a problem. I can't use that since I will run out of space if I do all of my work via my webpage. Please read the question again, sorry about that!